# Breakpoints are automatically removed when file saved

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, breakpoints

How can I stop Visual Studio Code to remove all the defined breakpoints in a file, when the file is saved?

I'm using version 1.16.1 now but the same behavior was happening on previous versions.

Comment: On version 1.14.1 breakpoints remain on file after saving. After this version, the behavior changed.